# Querying Google Fusion simple Query

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I want to query my google fusion to show certain data within a range that will be provided from a range slider.
I did everything requiring the code, but I am new to querying and I dont know the correct format. Basically It should be something like:

```
 "select geo(kml code column) from <tableid> where Population(my column) from <range1 to     range2> "
```

range1 and range2 should be fed by sliders values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"select geo(kml code column) from <tableid> where Population <= range2 and Population >= range1 "
```

Answer (score 0):

[reference](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_reference)

**SELECT**

```sql
To query for data, use the following syntax in an HTTP GET request:

SELECT  <column_spec> {, <column_spec>}* FROM <table_id>

{ WHERE <filter_condition> | <spatial_condition> { AND <filter_condition> }* }

{ GROUP BY <column_name> {, <column_name>}* }

{ ORDER BY <column_spec> { ASC | DESC } | <spatial_relationship> }

{ OFFSET <number> }

{ LIMIT <number> }

Note: Fusion Tables returns data in UTF-8 format.
```